# How to make an element disappear and stay gone after hovering over it?

Tags: css

So here is my code...

I understand how to make the text disappear by making it transparent but i want it to stay gone after hovering over it so it doesnt come back - how do I accomplish this?

```
.disappear {
     margin-top: 60px; 
     text-align: center;
     transition: all 5s ease .3s;
     font-family: Bungee Spice;
      }

 .disappear:hover {
 color: transparent;
   }
```

Comment: Read more about `display` property here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

`display: none;`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to make it run smoothly with pure CSS, so far, this is what I think is close to what you want to accomplish. So before hover, the animation to make it gone is already set, but the animation is not running yet, the animation will run only if the element is hovered. The problem here is that when it's hovered then it's unhovered before it's gone, the element will be *half gone* as the animation is paused.

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background: #dddddd;
}
.disappear {
    margin-top: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Bungee Spice;
    background: yellow;
    animation: example 5s linear forwards;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.disappear:hover {
    animation-play-state: running;  
}

@keyframes example {
    from {opacity: 1}
    to {opacity: 0}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    not disappear
    <div class="disappear">
        DISAPPEAR
    </div>
</div>
```

The better way would be to use javascript and use `onmouseover` to add the animation instead of using `:hover`, the difference is that when you onmouseout, the function is still executed (the animation persists). This is with JS:

```js
function fade(elm) {
  elm.style.animation = "example 5s linear forwards";
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: #dddddd;
}

.disappear {
  margin-top: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Bungee Spice;
  background: yellow;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    opacity: 1
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  not disappear
  <div class="disappear" onmouseover="fade(this)">
    DISAPPEAR
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you explain how id do it using java script? and thanks so much for your thoughtful response looking into ths now

Comment: Genius! I edited some out but it worked perfectly! what language is @animation?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: updated using javascript, @animation is still CSS, please accept if it does answer your question

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `onmouseover` and `remove()` like this

```js
function bye() {

  const dis = document.getElementById("dis");
  dis.remove();
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

div {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: xx-large;
  overflow: auto;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <h2 onmouseover="bye()" id="dis">will go on hover</h2>
</div>
```